# Publishing feature in Sharepoint 2010: Groups

Tags: feature, site-collection, publishing, groups

Someone told me a while ago that it isn't recommended to delete the groups that are created when activating the publishing feature on sitecollection-level. Anyone who has an idea why? I'd like to keep the amount of groups on the sites as minimal as possible, but I need the publishing...

Some of the extra groups that are created:

- All Authenticated Users
- Approvers
- Designers
- Hierarchy Managers
- NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users
- Quick Deploy Users
- Restricted Readers
- Style Resource Readers
- Viewers

And what about the document libraries? Can I delete some of those?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't going to use the groups, I can't think of a reason deleting them would be a problem EXCEPT that recreating any one of them can be a real pain. Each group is built up of a combination of settings for the 32 permissions. You might be better off leaving them just in case unless the EXCEPT above doesn't concern you.

Comment: Thanks Marc for the quick response. Do you also know about the lists, libraries,... that are created when activating the feature if it's safe to delete some?

Comment: You can delete those which you aren't using, but be sure you understand what each one is used for before doing so. While you are trying to tidy things up, you may well break things.